# How to quickly write an array of objects out to a worksheet column?

Tags: vba, class, excel

In a large, many-property class named cFoolish is this code fragment:

```
''''' Property Definitions
Private pID As Integer
Public Property Get ID() as Integer
    ID = pID
End Property
```

A code module declares a 1000 element array of cFoolish objects, and as part of a larger plan wants to write all 1000 .ID properties to a worksheet:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim MyArray(1 To 1000) As New cFoolish
    Dim rRange As Range

    Set rRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A1:A1000")
    Set rRange.Value = MyArray.ID '''''clearly doesn't work!
End Sub
```

I'm sorry, this is my first program using classes in VBA and I'm still pretty clueless.  The idea was to end up with the range A1:A1000 in worksheet "Test" be populated with the 1000 ID integers from the 1000 element array of cFoolish.

Thank you for any help!
Dave

Comment: I don't think Excel will write a one-dimensional array to a range (which is two-dimensional). You need to loop through your array and store the values in a 2D array, then write the 2D array to the range.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers You can write a 1D array to a range - if it's a row it will work, if it's a column you just need to use `WorksheetFunction.Transpose()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop as you must address each instance individually.  You can preload the values into an array and perform a *single* sheet update:

```
Dim MyArray(1 To 1000) As New cFoolish

Dim vals(1 To 1000) As Integer
For i = 1 To 1000
    vals(i) = MyArray(i).ID
Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A1:A1000") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vals)
```

Comment: Minor point: more efficient to just write to a 2D array in the first place rather than calling Transpose.

Comment: Thank you all very much for responding to my question, especially 
Alex K. who had the most complete answer, Macro Man who noted the use of WorksheetFunction.Transpose() to flip the 1D row to a column, and Rory who noted an efficiency improvement in using an array configured as a single column:   Dim vals(0 to 1000, 1 to 1) as integer.  I have tried to upvote the answer, but I lack the 15 points of reputation needed.  I do thank you all very much!  Best regards, Dave